# Automatically restart Kafka Stream in java

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, apache-kafka-streams

The problem that I am facing is my Kafka Stream(1 thread) goes down unexpectedly due to some error. What I want to do is that if there is an error in Kafka stream consumer, it is identified and the stream is restarted automatically via a cron so that it removes the pain of constantly monitoring it. Is there any appropriate way to do this?

Until now I have tried using `stream.start()` on the same stream instance that got the error but it didn't work.

Comment: You cannot re-used a KafkaStreams instance. So you have to close the KafkaStreams instance and create a new one when an uncaught exception happened. I'm working on the http://azkarrastreams.io project that handles this kind of scenario natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can not reuse a stream right now. However in 2.8 (a few months away) there is plans to allow for stream threads to be replaced in a handler.